# Explanation on XML Signature

Tags: xml-signature

I am reading stuffs on xml signature from a couple of days as it is a part of one of my assignments. Till now, What I understood is We can sign any type of data with it. I have gone through all the elements. When I look at them they all seem to be easy and understandable. But as I go through them deeply, I find it difficult to understand most of them. I mean some of the elements like **Signaturevalue,CanonicalizationMethod,transform,etc**. So my question is Is there any material which gives **detailed explanation on xmlsignature?** Which also provides some basic examples for better understanding of concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check these websites

XML Security Library
http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/

An Introduction toXML Signature and XML Encryptionwith XMLSec
http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~pcamacho/tutorial/web/xmlsec/xmlsec.html

Signing an XML document using XMLDSIG
http://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig.html

The last one gives almost all necessary detail to implement a basic xml signature with enveloped signature.